# exec xp_cmdshell 'sc \\<servername/serverip> start <service_name>'

Tags: sql-server

When I execute this on sql server on another machine (in same sub net) I am getting "**Access is denied**". But when I did it from command prompt (sc \ start ) it is working.

Please advice why I am getting access denied when I am doing it from sql server using exec xp_cmdshell cmd

Comment: As more of DBA admin task than program development, this might be a better fit at dba.SE.

Comment: What permissions or role is assigned to the account being used to execute the command from SQL Server?

Comment: Shawn Melton: I used windows authentication (<machine name>/Administrator) and sql authentication (sa) to login to sql server and execute the stored procedure. But none of them work. But when I changed the log on type of "SQL Server (COACHINGSOLNS)" service from Local system to Administrator it worked. But I cant do that, without changing the log on type of sql server service . How can I do this. Is there anything like exec xp_cmdshell run as /user: administartor 'sc \\<servername/serverip> start <service_name>' Plz advice

Comment: @user1745679 Please don't post comments as answers.  Feel free to add this back into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a double hop impersonation that requires [delegation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/autz_auth_stuff/kerberos-delegation).